# RavenDb 4.0 - RavenJValue from Raven.Abstractions

Tags: c#, ravendb, ravendb4

I am migrating to `RavenDB 4.0`, as a part of Migration I came across setting the meta-data `session.Advanced.GetMetadataFor(data)["Raven-Expiration-Date"] = new RavenJValue(data.Promotion.DateToUtc);`

The only place I found that type is `Raven.Abstractions` reference, but that on is in version `3.5` Is that still valid for `4.0`?

Also, I am not sure if that Raven.Abstractions package comes together with `RavenDB 4.0` package, and it looks like those things depend on each other.

Anybody has any kind of experience with that? I understand `RavenDB 4.0` is not final yet, and there might be some of the issues.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That value has changed. For 4.0, you need to use:

`session.Advanced.GetMetadataFor(data)["@expires"] = data.Promotion.DateToUtc.ToString("O");`

Comment: Oh I see, thats even better than use RavenJValue as it used to be. Thanks.